# Add CMD commands to gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a gulp task that I want to add the CMD command of `cls` to. The purpose of this is that the console get's populated with data each time you save a change on a file. The result is pages and pages of information about what files were edited, and about `browser-sync` status.

I have the following:

```
gulp.task("default", done => {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: siteURL
  });
  gulp.watch("_jade/*.jade", gulp.parallel(["templates"]));
  gulp.watch("_jade/_includes/*.jade", gulp.parallel(["includes"]));
  gulp.watch("_sass/*.scss", gulp.parallel(["styles"]));
  gulp.watch("_js/", gulp.parallel(["js"]));
  done();
});
```

I've already tried implementing `gulp-run-command`, to no avail. Maybe someone has a way to keep the console clean?

Comment: You can try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-exec

Comment: No luck so far. Do you have specific instructions?